# Angularjs Controller Error [$controller:ctrlreg]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I am working on a website and it's running fine (online). I used angularjs for the javascript. I already minified all my angularjs code. But now, I put some new files called `app-v2.js` which is a javascript file. But, the new files I added seems not working. When I see the console of my browser it says like this `Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=v2-ctrl`. That errors mean that the controller `v2-ctrl` was not found/defined. But when i double check my files and codes it was there. Why is this happening? Here is my `app-v2.js` code:

```
(function(){

'use strict';

 app.controller('v2-ctrl',['$scope','$http','$sce','$window','$timeout','$location','$route','$document', function($scope,$http,$sce,$window,$timeout,$location,$route,$document){

$scope.getAwards = function(){
    $http.post('angular?ng=awards',{}).then(function(response){
    $scope.awards = response.data;

    for(var i = 0; i<response.data.length;i++){
        response.data[i].award_title = response.data[i].award_title.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
    }
    $scope.awards = response.data;

    });
  };
})();
```

**NOTE:** The `app` was already defined on the another `js file`.

I hope someone can help me. I'm really stucked.

**HEY:** You can see actual code here
[Click this](http://www.cvsrrc.com/about-us)

Comment: problem is somewhere else. post your js file

Comment: @Sajeetharan Please visit website mentioned above sir.

Comment: Please post your HTML where this line is written `<div ng-view="" ng-show="statechange" class="ng-scope" data-ng-animate="1">`. Also please post your routing configuration.